# Replace values in a dataframe column based on randomized array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an original (numpy) array with integers:

```
arraya= array([550045586,   4926233,  29153854, ..., 550008337,  29387809,
          516004], dtype=int64)
```

and a randomized (nummpy) array:

```
arrayrandom = array([11000911017,    98523957,   583076377, ..., 11000166037,
         587755477,    10319377], dtype=int64)
```

​How can i replace all values in a dataframe column when they are in arraya by the value of arrayrandom. For example:

```
df['Example'] =
550045586
...
111
...
550008337
```

Should be:

```
df['Example'] =
11000911017
...
111
...
11000166037
```

The value in the dataframe column should only be replaced by the value in arrayrandom, if the value in a row exists in an arraya

Comment: Need `df['Example'] = arrayrandom` ?

Comment: No, when the value in the dataframe column occurs in the arraya, it has to be replaced by arrayrandom

Comment: its not the same question

Comment: hmm, so need `df['Example'] = df['Example'].replace(dict(zip(arraya, arrayrandom)))` ?

Comment: if that solutions maps the belonging arraya to array random

Comment: Sorry, not understand. what is logic for replace?

Comment: from sample data seems `dict(zip(arraya, arrayrandom))` is dict for repalcement